# How to prevent browser from storing Blobs?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, blob

I have a low memory device (some cheapo Windows tablet) that is running Firefox in order to display a internal site that has some live camera feeds. The site keeps crashing Firefox and it seems to be because of the browser saving each and every `Blob` that is created. Below is an interval that I have that is grabbing the latest frame some a server:

```
setInterval( function () {
    if ( frontShown ) {
        fetch( 'http://192.168.7.2:888/image/Main' ).then( function ( response ) {
            return response.blob();
        } ).then( function ( myBlob ) {
            var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL( myBlob );
            FrontDoorVideo.src = objectURL;
        } );
    } else {
        fetch( 'http://192.168.7.2:888/image/Back' ).then( function ( response ) {
            return response.blob();
        } ).then( function ( myBlob ) {
            var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL( myBlob );
            BackDoorVideo.src = objectURL;
        } );
    }
}, 500 );
```

Attached is a screenshot of the `Blobs` filling up the Sources tab in Chrome DevTools:
[image: Sources Tab in Chrome]

Also a screenshot of the Network tab:

[image: Network Tab in Chrome]

How do I prevent the browser from caching all of these blobs? I was thinking about a service worker that would delete from the cache on each new fetch.

Comment: To avoid http cache, you have to set your server sends a no-cache header in the response. To let GC collect the blob's data revoke the blobURIs when not needed anymore. But actually, why do you even fetch the resource as Blob? If you are sending an mjpeg stream, then let the `<img>` tag handle the stream itself, it won't load what it doesn't need.

Comment: I do not control the headers that the server sends, so the cache headers can't be sent. So I tried setting the `src` straight to the URL, it did work on the desktop Chrome but on the WinBook tablet, the image got cached and never updates.

Comment: But these images come from an ip camera right? You must have controls over it and its server, otherwise throw it away, it's a giant hole on your private life. Under the hood it probably uses something like [motion](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion/blob/master/motion_guide.html) to produce the still images you get. And by default, most of these cams also do produce a single [mjpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) stream per cam that your browser will be able to render as is, without any use of a setInterval or fetch at all.

Comment: The cameras themselves only expose an rtsp stream. I have a program running called Blue Iris which takes that and converts it to various other consumable formats such as iframes. I can control the image quality and such but not so much the server stuff.

Comment: I don't know Blue Iris at all, but [it seems](https://community.openhab.org/t/blue-iris-integration-http-binding-rest-api/10838/2#post_2) that by default it does output an mjpeg stream in */mjpg/{cam-short-name}/video.mjpg* So you might want to check *http://192.168.7.2:888/mjpg/Main/video.mjpg* and *http://192.168.7.2:888/mjpg/Back/video.mjpg*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is that an Object-URL is kept in memory until it's revoked.

Try doing:

```
var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL( myBlob );
FrontDoorVideo.onload = revokeURL;   // add onload handler before src
FrontDoorVideo.src = objectURL;
```

Then use a common handler:

```
function revokeURL() {
  URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);     // remove URL reference
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, however, the Sources tab still shows `Blobs` filling up. I added a breakpoint in the handler and the URLs seem to be correct and match the `Blobs` but they still don't get removed. As I understand the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL), it doesn't actually delete it. All it does is mark the object as garbage-collectable, the GC still has to be the one to remove it?

Comment: @GPinskiy yes, the GC has to collect/remove it. It shouldn't take too much time though. Did you try to use the Performance recorder in the console and see if the GC collects over time? Are there any other references not shown in the question that holds a reference to the original blob?

Comment: I do not have a reference to the blob anywhere else but here. As for the Performance recorder, I have used it, but I have no idea what I am looking at. Will have to read up on it before its useful to me in this instance.

Comment: I do have to admit that this solution so far works a lot better than anything else. Firefox has stopped crashing, and the image updates correctly. I still get a low memory warning every couple of hours but that might be something to live with.

Comment: @GPinskiy an alternative to use blob-urls is to force the original url to not cache by adding for example a timestamp to it as argument: `.src = "http://192.168.7.2:888/image/Main?" + Date.now();`.